# Check before inserting correct in datastore gae?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

first of all sorry for my English i use Google Translate.

I am new in using Google App Engine, and I place a user, but first I need to check that one already exists, and I note with email "is unique key" and let me know if I'm doing it the right way.

The pseudo code would be this:

class NewUser

```
if not exist mail
    put user to database
    return true
else
    return false
```

Servlet InsertUser:

```
if not NewUser.put
    redirect login.jsp
else
    redirect user.jsp
```

And this is the code:

NewUser class:

```
public static boolean insert(String name, String mail, String password) {
    DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory
            .getDatastoreService();

    Key k = KeyFactory.createKey(User.class.getSimpleName(), mail);

    if (!userExist(k)) {
        Entity user = new Entity(k);
        user.setProperty("name", name);
        user.setProperty("password", Encrypt.MD5(password));
        datastore.put(user);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}

private static boolean userExist(Key key) {
    DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory
            .getDatastoreService();

    Query q = new Query(key).setKeysOnly();

    List<Entity> ent = datastore.prepare(q).asList(
            FetchOptions.Builder.withDefaults());

    return (ent.isEmpty() || ent == null) ? false : true;
}
```

And the Servlet:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {
    resp.setContentType("text/plain");

    resp.sendRedirect(NewUser.insert(req.getParameter("name"),
            req.getParameter("mail"), req.getParameter("password")) ? "jsps/user.jsp"
            : "jsps/login.jsp");

}
```

Can I make it check the email without a query?

This code works, but i am looking for suggestion on how to make it better.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this actually work for you? `Query q = new Query(key)` creates an ancestor query where `key` is parent entity. It does not query for entity with this key: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Query#Query(com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key)

Comment: The query works. The key entities User, is email.
It is faster to consult with key ancestor?

Answer (score 0):

To check if Entity exists you could simply use [`get(key)`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/DatastoreService#get%28com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key%29):

```
private static boolean userExist(Key key) {
    DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory
        .getDatastoreService();

    try {
        datastore.get(key);
    } catch (EntityNotFoundException e){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: With this method, considering that almost always generate exceptions, it will not roll away performance?
It would be better to avoid the exception?